# Как сделать SELF JOIN в Django ORM?

Tags: django

У меня есть вот такой ORM запрос.

```
     paymentsss =  Transaction.objects.all().select_related('currency',
 'payment_source__payment_type', 'deal__service',
                  'deal__service__contractor').filter(
                payment_date__range=[date1, date2],).order_by('-id')
```

Мне надо добавить сюда SELF JOIN таблицы `payment_source` , чтобы вывести эти два поля по `payer_id`(левый столбец):

Чуть-чуть модифицировав запрос(добавлены алиасы ps и psc и нижняя строчка добавлена), полученный из Django ORM(который выше),вышел такой SQL-запрос(PostgreSQL):

```
    SELECT "processing"."transaction"."id",
       "processing"."transaction"."currency_id",
       "processing"."transaction"."deal_id",
       "processing"."transaction"."payment_source_id",
       "processing"."transaction"."payment_date",
       "processing"."transaction"."amount",
       "processing"."transaction"."status",
       "processing"."transaction"."context",
       "processing"."currency"."id",
       "processing"."currency"."iso_name",
       "processing"."currency"."minor_unit",
       "processing"."deal"."id",
       "processing"."deal"."service_id",
       "processing"."deal"."currency_id",
       "processing"."service"."id",
       "processing"."service"."contractor_id",
       "processing"."service"."name",
       "processing"."service"."description",
       "processing"."contractor"."id",
       "processing"."contractor"."name",
       "ps"."id",
       "ps"."payment_type_id",
       "ps"."source_details",
       "processing"."payment_type"."id",
       "processing"."payment_type"."name",
       "psc"."source_details"
FROM "processing"."transaction"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "processing"."currency" ON ("processing"."transaction"."currency_id" = "processing"."currency"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "processing"."deal" ON ("processing"."transaction"."deal_id" = "processing"."deal"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "processing"."service" ON ("processing"."deal"."service_id" = "processing"."service"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "processing"."contractor" ON ("processing"."service"."contractor_id" = "processing"."contractor"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "processing"."payer_payment_source" AS "ps" ON ("processing"."transaction"."payment_source_id" = "ps"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "processing"."payment_type" ON ("ps"."payment_type_id" = "processing"."payment_type"."id")
LEFT OUTER JOIN "processing"."payer_payment_source" AS "psc" ON ("ps"."payer_id" = "psc"."payer_id") AND "psc"."payment_type_id" = 'bank_card_details'
WHERE
    "processing"."transaction"."payment_date" BETWEEN '2019-10-02T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz AND '2019-10-31T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz

ORDER BY "processing"."transaction"."id" DESC
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно провернуть тоже самое через Django ORM? Через Raw-запросы мне не подходит, поскольку дальше этот запрос ещё надо фильтровать, а это уже другая проблема.

UPD: Изменил payer_id на `payer = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='card')`. Но в запросе не появляется ничего нового... Скорее всего надо что-то изменить в view...

Answer (score 0):

ответ к вашей проблеме смотрите здесь https://www.w3resource.com/PostgreSQL/postgresql-left-join.php

```
SELECT
    `ace`.`id`,
    `ace`.`version_id`,
    `ace`.`obj`,
    `ace`.`subj`,
    `ace`.`ACE_Type`,
    `ace`.`ACE_Inheritance`,
    `ace`.`ACE_Rights`
FROM `ace`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `core_subject`
ON (`ace`.`subj` = `core_subject`.`name`)
WHERE `ace`.`version_id` = 296
```

Comment: На чистом SQL у меня уже есть решение, спасибо. Меня интересует, есть ли решение этой задачи через Django ORM. Хотелось бы сделать именно через неё, чтобы было удобно фильтровать Queryset в последующем использовании.